# html5 habilitar geolocalização no TChromium em Delphi

Tags: html5, delphi, google-chrome, geolocalização

Eu uso o componente Chromium em meus projetos Delphi para navegar em páginas html porém ele não mostra nenhuma interação quando o usuário tenta acessar página que solicita acesso a geolocalização, como faço para habilitar isso no TChromium?

Segue um código html simples que estou testando, neste caso deveria aparecer uma caixa de dialogo pedido permissão para usar a geolocalização.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Clique aqui para saber suas coordenadas aproximadas</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Clique</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```